# Tab Bar Item Stopped Changing ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboard

My TabBarController was working fine but stopped working after adding custom Images and removing titles. I put custom images and also added a Navigation Bar behind the Tab Bar Controller on the stack. Before it was navigating to VCs when I click on the Tab Bar items but now it just doesn't do anything. The selected after the viewLoads is also highlighted.

The relationships also seems fine on TabBarController (`relationship 'viewcontrollers' to item'`)

What may be the reason?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of putting the navigation controller before your tab bar, try inserting after the tab bar. Connect the segue from the tab bar to the view controller.

This does answer your question of "What may be the reason?"
I would have put it as a comment but i lack the reputation to do so.